# fetch customer field on wp_posts from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress, I have added "city_name" to wp_posts, now i am using the following query but did not getting result according to city_name.

```
$query_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'city_name' => 'karachi',     
                    'showposts' => 7
                    //'offset'=> 0,
                    //'posts_per_page'=>2
                );
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Answer (score 1):

**store city name in meta field using `update_post_meta` wordpress function**

`update_post_meta('post id here','city_name','karachi')`

**and now you can query for this field like so :**

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'city_name',
           'value' => 'karachi'

       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

**Refer Here : [Wp Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)**